# Embedded Applet in swing app causes paint problem

Tags: java, swing

What I have is an Application that uses swing components (jpanel, jbutton, jlabel, etc), however I have to use an old PDF viewer (upgrade is not an option) that is based on java.awt.Applet (com.adobe.acrobat.Viewer). The problem comes when I am trying to display it, it draws properly however since this PDF viewer is inside a JScrollPane, it draws over all of the swing components (over the scroll bars and the menu).

Does anyone know how to make the PDF viewer act nicely and not to draw over other components.

Any suggestions are appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at [*Mixing heavy and light components*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/), which describes some new support for this. I understand "upgrade is not an option", but the discussion may yield some insight.

Comment: Thanks for the guid it solved the problem (well it enlightened the problem).